# Проблема с кодировкой в IE

Tags: php

Делаю вход на сайт с ajax. Проверяю на IE и возникает проблема с кодировкой.
��� �� - вместо букв при ответе от сервера после ввода данных.
Кодировка на странице входа

```
 <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
```

А  на код обработчика (пока выглядит так)

```
<?php
echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />';
exit('Типа вошел');
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

уберите из кода обработчика строку 
`echo '<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />';` , а вместо неё добавьте 
    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251");